# Why do I have to run and change one video setting before Raptr can optimize games?

Tags: performance, raptr

I reinstalled my PC as I needed to replace some hard drives. After reinstalling Raptr, I noticed that most games in my library had a screen saying “You need to run this game and change at least one video setting before we can optimize it.”

Why is this? I always believed that [Raptr optimization](http://raptr.com/info/faq#amd_optimized) was based on the settings detected from the community with the same/similar hardware setup. What difference does it make if I start the game or not first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because most games write their config files into user space only after the first launch, which is quite normal. So in order for raptr to change it, it must exist first.

Comment: That makes totally sense. It would likely be easier to change/add section to an existing configuration file that to introduce issues by making one when one did not already exist. Thank you for thinking it through for me.

Comment: @Aeyoun Didn't have to think there, I am a programmer and game dev myself.